# Java setText from another Controller, but UI dont refresh

Tags: java, javafx

i have 2 controllers. I want to set the value of tf_fileName from my GlobalOptionsFileNameController. The value is set and i can work with it, but the TextField dont Update the View (i dont see the new value).

Here is my Code. Sry it could be a duplicate, but i dont found a working way for me at the other posts.

```
package configHelp;

import burninbuilder.GlobalOptionsController;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author Sandro
 */
public class GlobalOptionsFileNameController implements Initializable {

    @FXML Button btn_help;
    @FXML RadioButton rb_local;
    @FXML RadioButton rb_server;
    @FXML TextField txt_filename;
    @FXML TextField txt_serverName;
    @FXML TextField txt_path;
    @FXML Button btn_addNr;
    @FXML Button btn_addDriveSN;
    @FXML Button btn_ok;

    Stage test = new Stage();

    GlobalOptionsController optionsController;
    public void getController() throws IOException{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/burninbuilder/GlobalOptions.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
        optionsController = loader.getController();
        System.out.println(this.optionsController);
    }

    public void setFileName(ActionEvent ev){
        if(rb_local.isSelected()){
            optionsController.setNameLocal(txt_filename.getText());
            System.out.println(optionsController.tf_fileName.getText());
        }else if(rb_server.isSelected()){
            String fileNameServer="//"+txt_serverName.getText()+"/"+txt_path.getText();
            optionsController.setNameLocal(fileNameServer);
        }   
    }

    public void test(){
        txt_filename.setText("test");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        btn_ok.setOnAction(this::setFileName);
        try {
            getController();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GlobalOptionsFileNameController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }    

}
```

Class where i want to set and refresh the TextField.

```
    package burninbuilder;

import configHelp.GlobalOptionsFileNameController;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import logic.GlobalOptions;

public class GlobalOptionsController implements Initializable {

//
GlobalOptions globalOptionsSingleton = GlobalOptions.getInstance();

Stage fileNameOptions = new Stage();

@FXML public TextField tf_fileName;

    }
}

GlobalOptionsFileNameController fileAssistentController;
public void fileNameOptions(ActionEvent ev){
    try {
        if(fileNameOptions.getScene()==null){
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/configHelp/globalOptionsFileName.fxml")); 
            Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
            fileAssistentController = loader.getController();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            fileNameOptions.setTitle("Assistent zum festlegen der Speicherorte und Dateinamen");
            fileNameOptions.getIcons().add(new javafx.scene.image.Image("pictures/app-icon.png")); 
            fileNameOptions.setScene(scene);
            fileNameOptions.setResizable(false);
            fileNameOptions.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            fileNameOptions.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

            fileNameOptions.show();
        }else{
            fileNameOptions.show();
        }             
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("AddWindow: "+ex);
        }
}

@FXML
public void setFileName(String name){
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tf_fileName.setText("test");
        System.out.println("TextField:"+tf_fileName.getText());
    }
});
}

@FXML
public void setNameLocal(String name){
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        tf_fileName.setText(null);
        tf_fileName.setText(name);
    }
});
}


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    filename_options.setOnAction(this::fileNameOptions);
    tabpane.setTabMinWidth(94);
    btn_ok.setOnAction(this::getGlobalOptions);
    cb_html.setOnMousePressed(this::setFileEx);
    tf_fileName.setOnMouseExited(this::addExTextField);
    tf_hour.setOnKeyTyped(this::onlyNumber);
    tf_min.setOnKeyTyped(this::onlyNumber);
    tf_duration.setOnKeyTyped(this::onlyNumber);
    tf_fail.setOnKeyTyped(this::onlyNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code? Dumping everything you've got will make it harder for people to follow, and might get less people attracted to your question.

Comment: Yes, sry. I edit the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller you retrieve in `getController()` is associated with a UI element (`root`, declared locally in the `getController()` method) that is never displayed. So calling methods on that controller instance cannot have any visible effect in your UI. I assume you are loading the `GlobalOptions.fxml` file elsewhere and displaying its contents. You need a reference to the controller you get from that loader (not some arbitrary loader whose loaded contents you discard).

Since the code in your `fileNameOptions(...)` method in `GlobalOptionsController` already has a reference to the `GlobalOptionsFileNameController`, you should probably just use that relationship to transfer the information.

Create a read only `StringProperty` in the `GlobalOptionsFileNameController`, and set it from the `setFileName(...)` method:

```
public class GlobalOptionsFileNameController {

    // ...

    private ReadOnlyStringWrapper filename = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper();

    // ...

    public String getFilename() {
       return filename.get() ;
    }

    public ReadOnlyStringProperty filenameProperty() {
        return filename.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public void setFileName(ActionEvent ev){
        if(rb_local.isSelected()){
            filename.set(txt_filename.getText());
        }else if(rb_server.isSelected()){
            String fileNameServer="//"+txt_serverName.getText()+"/"+txt_path.getText();
            filename.set(fileNameServer);
        }   
    }

    // ...
}
```

You can also get rid of the `GlobalOptionsController` reference and the `getController()` method from `GlobalOptionsFileNameController`.

Now in `GlobalOptionsController` just observe the property and update the text field when it changes:

```
public class GlobalOptionsController {

    // ...

    public void fileNameOptions(ActionEvent ev){
        try {
            if(fileNameOptions.getScene()==null){
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/configHelp/globalOptionsFileName.fxml")); 
                Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
                GlobalOptionsFileNameController fileAssistentController = loader.getController();

                fileAssistentController.filenameProperty().addListener((obs, oldFilename, newFilename) -> 
                    tf_fileName.setText(newFilename));

                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                fileNameOptions.setTitle("Assistent zum festlegen der Speicherorte und Dateinamen");
                fileNameOptions.getIcons().add(new javafx.scene.image.Image("pictures/app-icon.png")); 
                fileNameOptions.setScene(scene);
                fileNameOptions.setResizable(false);
                fileNameOptions.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                fileNameOptions.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

                fileNameOptions.show();
            }else{
                fileNameOptions.show();
            }             
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("AddWindow: "+ex);
            }
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the awnser. Can you show me a bit of code for this?
1. I have to create a FXML-Loader with GlobalOptions.fxml
2. load() the loader, but with what? If nots the root element?
3. use the Controller with different methods in GlobalOptions.fxml

Is this right? And what do you mean with elsewhere if not in the other controller?